# crawl the lazy-loading webpage but the server responded with a status of 504

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, lazy-loading

I use python and selenium to crawl the quora which is lazy loading (I think something of AJAX). So I iteratively use selenium to send the order "window.scrollBy(0,1500);" to the browser which send it to the sever.
However, during this process, once the server returns: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)", the page just keeps loading without anything new. My code does not break down and I check the console of browser to find out this error. My code can be seen below:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(new_url)
try:
    for i in range(300):
        time.sleep(6)
        print i
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1500);")
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

appendResults(existingList, browser, File)
browser.quit()
```

So how can I keep scrolling down the page even one query is denied? Or except selenium, are there any other tools/libraries/methods to crawl pages with lazy loading? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's a real problem with the server then

Comment: Maybe try `self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @boardrider, thanks for your advice but no significant improvement.